# JWT Auth with Servicestack Ormlite - Generated Bearer token too large to use (>4096)

Tags: jwt, ormlite-servicestack

I'm migrating my ServiceStack Ormite MVC application to use the JWTAuthProvider for stateless auth. I have this working by authenticating as normal, and setting the returned BearerToken and RefreshToken on a successful auth:

```
using (var authService = HostContext.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>(ServiceStackRequest))
{
var response = await authService.PostAsync(new Authenticate
{
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
    UserName = model.UserName,
    Password = model.Password,
    RememberMe = true,
});

var authResponse = response.GetDto() as AuthenticateResponse;

Response.Cookies.Append("ss-tok", authResponse.BearerToken, new CookieOptions() {...});
Response.Cookies.Append("ss-reftok", authResponse.RefreshToken, new CookieOptions() {...});
}
```

This appears to work for some users and not for others. The problem seems to be that user accounts with a lot of permissions end up with much larger `BearerToken` values, some over 4096, so these cannot be set for the `ss-tok` cookie.

The [JWT Auth provider docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) provide references to the `CreatePayloadFilter` and the `PopulateSessionFilter`, however these are only used when creating a session from a token, not the other way around. I want to filter out items (the permissions in particular) when serializing to a token.

Ideally the permissions would be excluded if there are too many (or always be excluded if that's not possible) and would be lazy-loaded when accessed. This may be possible with a custom AuthUserSession inheriting from the base AuthUserSession that Lazy-loads the Permissions, but I don't know how I could do this without the JWT Provider loading the permissions to serialise too.

Comment: CreatePayloadFilter as the name indicates is invoked when creating the payload, I.e. it’s the inverse of PopulateSessionFilter

Comment: @mythz I've tried setting `CreatePayloadFilter = (payload, session) =>             payload["Permissions"] = null` in the JwtAuthProvider but this makes no difference. Do these map directly to the IAuthSession?

Comment: Did you inspect the payload dictionary you're changing? What made you guess & try to change "Permissions"? is it in the docs somewhere? Permissions are stored in "perms".

Comment: FYI you can also inspect the contents of a JWT Token with https://jwt.io or using [x inspect-jwt](https://docs.servicestack.net/post-command#inspect-jwts) with the x dotnet tool.

Comment: @mythz I did end up inspecting,a changing it to "perms" and it now works. I'm going to split the permissions into two categories (adding an extra extended permissions field to the CustomUserAuthSession) and have the extended permissions lazy-load.